# MonoGame/XNA Mouse Offsets

Tags: xna, mouse, offset, monogame, getstate

I am trying to use `Mouse.GetState()` for my menu selection. Currently, it will only highlight if I hover over a region left and up from where the menu is.  I used DrawString to display the mouses coordinates and found that the 0,0 point wasn't in the top left of my monitor or in the top left of the game window.  It was somewhere about 100,100 pixels from the top left of the screen.  Also, the 0,0 point moves every time I run the programme.

I looked at others people who have had the same problem but wasn't able to solve it.  I tried using `Mouse.WindowHandle = this.Window.Handle;` in my `Initialize()` but it didn't nothing.  I have two monitors and when I forced the game in fullscreen it would open on my second monitor so I disabled it but the problem remains.

here is a link to my code http://pastebin.com/PNaFADqp

**Game1 class:**

```
public class Game1 : Game
{
    GraphicsDeviceManager graphics;
    SpriteBatch spriteBatch;
    SpriteFont spriteFont;

    public const int WINDOW_HEIGHT = 800;
    public const int WINDOW_WIDTH = 600;

    public int tree;

    public TitleScreen titleScreen;
    public SATDemo satDemo;
    public SeparatingAxisTest separatingAxisTest;
    public SATWithAABB sATWithAABB;

    GameState currentState;

    public static Dictionary<string, Texture2D> m_textureLibrary = new Dictionary<string, Texture2D>();
    public static Dictionary<string, SpriteFont> m_fontLibrary = new Dictionary<string, SpriteFont>();

    public Game1()
    {
        graphics = new GraphicsDeviceManager(this);
        Content.RootDirectory = "Content";
        graphics.PreferredBackBufferHeight = WINDOW_HEIGHT;
        graphics.PreferredBackBufferWidth = WINDOW_WIDTH;
    }

    protected override void Initialize()
    {
        Mouse.WindowHandle = this.Window.Handle;
        //enable the mousepointer
        IsMouseVisible = true;
        currentState = GameState.TitleScreen;
        //sets the windows mouse handle to client bounds handle

        base.Initialize();
    }

    public void RequestSATDemo()
    {
        currentState = GameState.RequestSATDemo;
    }

    protected override void LoadContent()
    {
        // Create a new SpriteBatch, which can be used to draw textures.
        spriteBatch = new SpriteBatch(GraphicsDevice);


        m_textureLibrary.Add("Pixel", Content.Load<Texture2D>("White_Pixel"));
        m_fontLibrary.Add("Font", Content.Load<SpriteFont>("MotorwerkOblique"));

        titleScreen = new TitleScreen();
        satDemo = new SATDemo();
        separatingAxisTest = new SeparatingAxisTest();
        sATWithAABB = new SATWithAABB();
     }

    public void RequestSeparatingAxisTest()
    {
        currentState = GameState.SeparatingAxisTest;
    }

    public void RequestSATWithAABB()
    {
        currentState = GameState.SATWithAABB;
    }

    protected override void Update(GameTime gameTime)
    {
        MouseTestState = Mouse.GetState();
        switch (currentState)
        {
            case GameState.TitleScreen:
                {
                    titleScreen.Update(gameTime);
                    break;
                }
            case GameState.SeparatingAxisTest:
                {
                    separatingAxisTest.Update(gameTime);
                    break;
                }
            case GameState.SATWithAABB:
                {
                    sATWithAABB.Update(gameTime);
                    break;
                }
            case GameState.Exit:
                {
                    Exit();
                    break;
                }
            default:
                {
                    titleScreen.Update(gameTime);
                    break;
                }
        }

        base.Update(gameTime);
    }

    protected override void Draw(GameTime gameTime)
    {
        spriteBatch.Begin();

        spriteBatch.DrawString(m_fontLibrary["Font"], MouseTestState.ToString(), new Vector2(0, 0), Color.White);
        switch (currentState)
        {
            case GameState.TitleScreen:
                {
                    titleScreen.Draw(spriteBatch, spriteFont);
                    break;
                }
            case GameState.SeparatingAxisTest:
                {
                    separatingAxisTest.Draw(gameTime, spriteBatch);
                    break;
                }
            case GameState.SATWithAABB:
                {
                    sATWithAABB.Draw(gameTime, spriteBatch);
                    break;
                }
            case GameState.Exit:
                {
                    Exit();
                    break;
                }
            default:
                {
                    titleScreen.Update(gameTime);
                    break;
                }
        }

        spriteBatch.End(); 
        base.Draw(gameTime);
    }
}
```

**TitleScreen class:**

```
public class TitleScreen : Screen
{ 
    List<Button> buttonList = new List<Button>();
    public Menu mainMenu;
    public TitleScreen()
    {
        mainMenu = new Menu(new Vector2(200, 100), buttonList, 0); 
        buttonList.Add(new PushButton("Separating Axis Test"));
        buttonList.Add(new PushButton("SAT With AABB"));
        buttonList.Add(new PushButton("Awesome"));
        buttonList.Add(new PushButton("Awesomere"));
        buttonList.Add(new PushButton("Awesomere")); 
    }

    public override void Update(GameTime gametime)
    {
        mainMenu.Update(gametime);
    }

    public void Draw(SpriteBatch sB, SpriteFont sF)
    {
        mainMenu.Draw(sB, sF); 
    } 
}
```

**PushButton class:**

```
public class PushButton : Button
{
    string m_text;
    SpriteFont m_font;
    Color m_static, m_onClick, m_onHover;
    Texture2D m_sprite2D, m_onClick2D;

    static public int Pbuttoncount;

    //click processing
    bool m_clickedInside =  false,
         m_releasedInside = false,
         m_OnClicked =      false,
         selected =         false;

    Rectangle drawRectangle;

    public PushButton(string Text)
    {
        m_text = Text;

        drawRectangle = new Rectangle((int)Menu.m_position.X, (int)Menu.m_position.Y + (15 * Pbuttoncount), 200, 15);
        ButtonRegion = new Rectangle((int)Position.X, (int)Position.Y, 200, 15);
        Pbuttoncount++;
    }

    public PushButton(Rectangle ButtonRegion, SpriteFont Font, string Text, Color Static, Color OnClick, Color OnHover)
    {
        m_buttonRegion = ButtonRegion;
        m_font = Font;
        m_text = Text;
        m_static = Static;
        m_onClick = OnClick;
        m_onHover = OnHover;
        // drawRectangle = ButtonPosition(m_buttonRegion);
     }

    public PushButton(Rectangle ButtonRegion, Texture2D Sprite2D, Texture2D OnClick2D)
    {
        m_buttonRegion = ButtonRegion;
        m_sprite2D = Sprite2D;
        m_onClick2D = OnClick2D;
        //drawRectangle = ButtonPosition(m_buttonRegion);
    }

    public override void Update(GameTime gameTime)
    {
        MouseState currentMouse = Mouse.GetState();

        selected = MouseState(drawRectangle, currentMouse);
        m_clickedInside = ClickInside(currentMouse, m_lastMouseState);
        ReleaseInside(currentMouse, m_lastMouseState);

        if (selected && m_clickedInside && m_releasedInside)
            m_OnClicked = true;
        else
            m_OnClicked = false;

        m_lastMouseState = currentMouse;
    }

    public override void Draw(SpriteBatch spriteBatch, SpriteFont spriteFont, int buttonCount, Vector2 Position)
    {
        spriteBatch.Draw(Game1.m_textureLibrary["Pixel"], new Rectangle((int)Position.X + 10, (int)(Position.Y + 15 * buttonCount), 180, 15), Color.Wheat);

        if (selected)
            spriteBatch.DrawString(Game1.m_fontLibrary["Font"], m_text, new Vector2(Position.X + 15, Position.Y + 15 * buttonCount), Color.Orange);
        else
            spriteBatch.DrawString(Game1.m_fontLibrary["Font"], m_text, new Vector2(Position.X + 15, Position.Y + 15 * buttonCount), Color.Black);
    }
}
```

**Menu class:**

```
public class Menu
{
    List<Button> m_buttonList;
    float m_transparency;
    public int n = 0;
    public Rectangle buttonRegion, m_menuRegion, m_dimensions;
    static public Vector2 m_position;
    int m_WINDOW_HEIGHT = Game1.WINDOW_HEIGHT;
    int m_WINDOW_WIDTH = Game1.WINDOW_WIDTH;
    private Game1 m_managerClass;

    public Menu(Vector2 Position, List<Button> ButtonList, float Transparency)
    {
        m_position = Position;
        m_buttonList = ButtonList;
        m_transparency = Transparency;
        m_managerClass = new Game1();
    }

    public Rectangle MenuRegion
    {
        get { return m_menuRegion; }
        set { m_menuRegion = value; }
    }

    static public Vector2 Position
    {
        get { return m_position; }
    }

    public void Update(GameTime gametime)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < m_buttonList.Count; i++)
        {
            m_buttonList[i].Update(gametime);
            if (m_buttonList[0].OnClicked)
            {
                SeperatingAxisTest();
            }
        }
    }

    public void Draw(SpriteBatch sB, SpriteFont sF)
    {
        sB.Draw(Game1.m_textureLibrary["Pixel"], new Rectangle((int)m_position.X - 5, (int)m_position.Y - 10, (m_buttonList[0].ButtonRegion.Width + 10), (m_buttonList[0].ButtonRegion.Height * m_buttonList.Count) + 20), Color.Blue);
        for (int i = 0; i < m_buttonList.Count; i++)
        {
            m_buttonList[i].Draw(sB, sF, i, new Vector2(Position.X, Position.Y));
        } 
    }

    private void SeperatingAxisTest()
    {
        m_managerClass.RequestSeparatingAxisTest();
    }
}
```

**Program class:**

```
public static class Program
{
    [STAThread]
    static void Main()
    {
        using (var game = new Game1())
            game.Run();
    }
}
```

Let me know if you need anything else. I'm still learning and will sell my soul to you for an answer.

Comment: Link not found bruh. Add your code to your question. (Only relevant, minimal sample)

Comment: Sorry, I didn't know what was relevant to the problem.  I'm new to this.

Comment: Can you post your entry point also? `Program.cs` or something, the one which contains the `Main` method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `Menu` class is creating a new instance of `Game1`. This is, most likely, not what you want, since `Game1` is instantiated in the entry point for you app. The `Game1` instance has an instance of `TitleScreen`, which in turn has an instance of the `Menu` class, so a `Menu` should have no business creating its own game.

When this (other) instance is created, it invokes platform-specific (Windows) methods, creates an additional window handle (which is never shown) and configures the `Mouse.WindowHandle`.

And btw, setting `WindowHandle` manually [does absolutely nothing in Monogame](https://github.com/mono/MonoGame/blob/develop/MonoGame.Framework/Input/Mouse.cs#L104), so all these sources mentioning that are talking about XNA.

So, there are several remarks:

1. You should probably have a "screen manager" class which contains the current screen. It is strange to have a field of type `TitleScreen` in your game class, it should at least be of the base type (`Screen`), so that the game class draws and updates each screen transparently.
2. If you need a reference to the game class anywhere, don't instantiate a new one, but rather pass it along through the constructor.
3. `m_managerClass` is a bad name for a field which is actually a `Game`. Also google for C# naming conventions. Perhaps you even might want to download an existing monogame game template, e.g. check some of the [samples online](https://github.com/CartBlanche/MonoGame-Samples); the [NetRumble sample](https://github.com/CartBlanche/MonoGame-Samples/tree/master/NetRumble) seems to implement a screen manager.
4. Remove the `Mouse.WindowHandle` line, it should be set to your one-and-only game window by default.

**tl;dr** add the `Game1` as a parameter wherever you might need it (but only where you need it).

```
abstract class Screen
{
     private readonly Game1 _game;
     public Game1 Game 
     { get { return _game; } }

     public Screen(Game1 game)
     {
         _game = game;
     }
}

class TitleScreen : Screen 
{
     public TitleScreen(Game1 game)
         : base(game)
     { ... }
}

class Menu 
{
     private readonly Screen _screen;

     public Menu(Screen parentScreen, Vector2 pos, List<Button> list, float alpha)
     {
          _screen = parentScreen;
          ...

          // if you need the game instance, just use _screen.Game
     }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, Groo.  That fixed It.  I will look at it more tonight.  As you can see I'm currently using a switch statement in my game1 class which switches the public enum GameState changing the current screen.  If I were to make a screen manager class instead should I just move the switch statement to that class?  Going to watch this vid series to learn more https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=TOAGy2S8MC8.  Also going to brush up on my C# naming conventions

Comment: @Cody: the idea behind OOP (i.e. having one base `Screen` class or `IScreen` interface) is to remove the need for that switch statement. This would mean that you have a "current screen" field (e.g. `currentScreen`), and you set it to some screen instance (e.g. `titleScreen`). If all screens inherit from `Screen`, then your update/draw methods don't care which screen it is, i.e. you only have `currentScren.Update(gameTime);` and `currentScreen.Draw(gameTime);`, without a switch.

Comment: This also means that you don't need a separate "game state" variable (at least not for screens, perhaps for some actual state machine within a single screen), because your state (in terms of current screen) is completely defined by whatever `currentScreen` is pointing to.